# Understanding "Il se disait heureux d’être échappé aux affaires."

Tags: sens, verbes

The question is on the last sentence of this passage from Flaubert's L'Éducation sentimentale.

> Il était républicain ; il avait voyagé, il connaissait l’intérieur des théâtres, des restaurants, des journaux, et tous les artistes célèbres. qu’il appelait familièrement par leurs prénoms ; Frédéric lui confia bientôt ses projets ; il les encouragea.
>       
>   Mais il s’interrompit pour observer le tuyau de la cheminée, puis il marmotta vite un long calcul, afin de savoir « combien chaque coup de piston, à tant de fois par minute, devait, etc. » — Et, la somme trouvée, il admira beaucoup le paysage. **Il se disait heureux d’être échappé aux affaires.**

**Question**

1. Without changing the meaning, can we say instead:

> Il se disait heureux d’**avoir** échappé aux affaires.

2. Why is it grammatically correct to say *d’être échappé*?  (See Background below)
3. Can you take Flaubert's sentence as a model for any similar case?

That is, noting that we have:

> Il échappe aux affaires. => Il est heureux d’être échappé aux affaires.

can we then say:

> Il pense à Pierre. => Il est heureux d’être pensé à Pierre.

to mean, "He is glad to have thought about Pierre"?

**Background**

Thoughts behind question 2.

I understand that the republican (we'll call him that) said he was glad to have escaped from the affairs.  According to [this conjugation table](http://www.wordreference.com/conj/FrVerbs.aspx?v=%C3%A9chapper), *échapper* takes forms of *avoir* when going into a perfect tense.  So I would have expected *d’avoir échappé*, not *d’être échappé*.  I would have guessed that *d’être échappé* was in the passive voice.

In English the following would be a grammatically well formed sentence.  (You have to imagine a very special prison that is socially aware.)

> The prison was glad to be escaped from by the innocent captives.

The following would not be grammatically well formed.  But that's just what the Flaubert sentence looks like.

> I was glad to be escaped from business.

This last sentence would be well formed only if *escape* had a second meaning so that

> *to escape<sup>2</sup> someone* = *to allow someone to escape<sup>1</sup>*

If so:

> *glad to be escaped<sup>2</sup> from some place* = *glad to be allowed to escape<sup>1</sup> from some place*

Could this be (implicitly) what is going on with *échapper*?

Or should we rather understand that *échapper* sometimes takes *être* when going into a perfect (i.e. in just such context as the Flaubert sentence)?

Comment: The conjugation table that you cite does indeed mention only “avoir,” but [“Le Figaro’s table”](http://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/french/verb/echapper_auxiliaire-etre.html) and [“this one”](http://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/du/verbe/echapper-1.php) seem to say that “être”  can also be used. **Maybe** it’s one of the verbs that can use * être* when describing states or conditions resulting from the action (like [“cesser”, see the “Remark”](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cesser)), which could be the case in your sentence (and/or, as you surmised in passing, a passive use).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Votre première réflexion, *avoir échappé*, est pertinente, mais elle s’applique dans le cas de quelqu’un qui n’est pas rattrapé par une ou plusieurs affaires.

L’emploi vieilli du *verbe transitif* a un sens différent que l’on retrouve dans certains régionalismes,
*Échapper à, éviter, ne plus pouvoir tenir* :

> Nulle puissance ne peut échapper les mains de Dieu. (Bossuet)
>   Il suivit leur regard et, de stupeur, il échappa son colis sur ses pieds. (Lemelin) <sup>1</sup>

C’est un langage vieilli ; il est difficilement audible de nos jours car *[très peu usité](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=avoir%20%C3%A9chapp%C3%A9%2C%C3%AAtre%20%C3%A9chapp%C3%A9&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cavoir%20%C3%A9chapp%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%C3%AAtre%20%C3%A9chapp%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0)*.

*Verbe pronominal* (Sujet être animé) : *s’enfuir, se sauver, se mettre hors de portée, s’évader, s’éclipser*

> Elles se sont échappées à toutes jambes.
>   Il y a des prisonniers qui s’échappent. (Green) <sup>1</sup>

N.B. : de ce fait, on ne peut transposer la formulation.  Avec *penser* on peut dire :

> *Il pense à* Pierre. ⇒ Il est heureux *de penser à* Pierre.

... mais *être pensé* n’a pas de sens lorsqu’il s’agit de soi-même : je pense, je pense à, je pense que, j’ai pensé mourir (+infinitif)

Vous trouverez l'explication grammaticale dans *[Le discours direct, le discours indirect et le discours indirect libre :
Cours et exercices](http://www.education-et-numerique.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/discours-direct-indirect.docx)*

> 5. **« Il se disait heureux d'être échappé aux affaires. »** -- *Flaubert, L’Éducation sentimentale.*
>      Cette phrase est au discours indirect car elle est introduite par un verbe de parole et les propos du personnage sont pris en charge par le narrateur.

---

<sup>*Définitions extraites du petit Robert*</sup>

Comment: Thank you. Questions. 1. *l'emploi vieilli du verbe pronominal (Sujet être animé)* refers to the Flaubert sentence? (I ask this because the sample sentence that follows the remark, i.e. *Nulle puissance...*, does not use a pronominal verb, nor is the subject animate.) 2. *car elle est introduite pas un verbe de parole*.  Is that supposed to be *par un verbe*?

Comment: @Catomic -- Excellente observation ! Après avoir mélangé les § lors de la copie des références, j'ai repris et corrigé ma réponse, j'espère qu'elle répondra à vos interrogations.

Comment: Thank you again. Can I then take the Flaubert sentence as a model for those verbs for which a pronominal form exists, e.g. those you list (*s’enfuir*, *se sauver,* etc.)? For example, can I say *Il est heureux d'être sauvé* and *Il est heureux d'être éclipsé*? If yes, that would provide an excellent explanation (hypothesis) for the Flaubert sentence. Namely, *d'être échappé* is a form of the pronominal verb (in which *se* has been suppressed).

Comment: @Catomic -- J'utiliserais ces tournures ainsi :  *Il est heureux de s'être éclipsé* (d'avoir pu quitter la réunion sans être remarqué). *Il ne voulut pas* se laisser éclipser *par son camarade, il déploya son esprit* (Balzac). *Durant cette soirée, le figurant était malheureux d’être éclipsé par la vedette* ...

Comment: ... Du fait que c’est le narrateur qui a déjà utilisé le *se* il n’est pas répété pour ne pas être redondant, pour ne pas alourdir la phrase (cette réponse n’est pas d’un grammairien, la réponse grammaticale concernant les verbes de parole est dans le §5 ; mais comme Flaubert utilisait un '*gueuloir*' [une pièce où il lisait ses écrits à voix haute], répéter le *se* aurait cassé la prosodie :). On peut aussi penser que c'est la spécificité du verbe *échapper* (forme transitive) qui a influencé ce type de phrase qu'il me semble difficile de la transposer sur d'autres verbes.

Comment: Understood. I will remember *d’être échappé* and not try to generalize from it. Thanks again.